# Laravel Eloquent циклы

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть код:

```
$count = User::where('invite', $us->ref_code)->get();
foreach($count as $all){
    $all = 0;

    $payments = Unitpay::where('account', $user)->where('status', 1)->sum('sum');
    $payments2 = G2A::where('account', $user)->where('status', 'complete')->sum('amount');
    $deposits = Trades::where('account', $user)->where('status', 'success')->sum('sum');

    $all = $payments + $payments2 + $deposits;
}
```

Получаем пользователей, которых пригласил исходный пользователь. И складываем все пополнения этих юзеров, чтобы по итогу получить сумму всех пополнений приглашенных людей
Есть ли в Laravel Eloquent способ реализовать это без цикла, просто одним запросом?
На данный момент эти запросы занимают очень много времени

**Update:**

Сделал так:

```
$users= User::where('invite', $us->ref_code)->get();

$params['all_sum'] = 0;
foreach($users as $user){
$payments = $user->unitpay->where('status', 1)->sum('sum');
$payments2 = $user->g2a->where('status', 'complete')->sum('amount');
$deposits = $user->trades->where('status', 'success')->sum('sum');
$all = $payments + $payments2 + $deposits;

$params['all_sum'] += round($all, 2);
}
```

Но все равно запрос долго проходит, даже дольше чем раньше

Comment: Да это бред какой то.Зачем вам цикл,вынесите все за цикл,он тут бессмыслен

Comment: Так я и спрашиваю как вынести все это дело за цикл

Comment: `$users = User::where('invite', $user->ref_code)->get();
$all = 0;
foreach($users  as $user){
    $payments = Unitpay::where('account', $user->account)->where('status', 1)->sum('sum');
    $payments2 = G2A::where('account', $user->account)->where('status', 'complete')->sum('amount');
    $deposits = Trades::where('account', $user->account)->where('status', 'success')->sum('sum');

    $all += $payments + $payments2 + $deposits;
}`

Comment: И что? вы скинули мой же вариант, только я ошибся и $all объявил в цикле, не так перенес сюда код

Comment: "Запрос проходит долго" - а много записей? Индексы и т.п. используете в таблицах для увеличения производительности?

Comment: Пользователей в переборе может быть от 1 до 30000
Платежей суммарно более 100000

Индексы имеются

Answer (score 1):

Тут тебе точно нужно хорошо прописать сами модели, а не в контроллере все это обрабатывать.

В моделях тебе нужно расписать связи, типа (просто пример, чтобы понять в какую сторону копать):

```
class User extends Model {
     public function payments() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Unitpay', 'account');
     }
}
```

Затем, можно с использованием

```
::with(array('payments' => function($query) { ... }))
```

написать подзапрос и т.п.

Comment: Прошу прощения за столь долгий ответ. Попробовал так, как вы говорите, код получился такой.

Модель:

`public function unitpay() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Unitpay', 'account');
    }
 
 public function g2a() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\G2A', 'steam_id');
 }

 public function trades() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\TradeLog', 'user_id');
 }`

Comment: А получить данные пытался так:

`User::with(array('unitpay' => function($query){ 
   $query->where('status', 1);
  }))->with(array('g2a' => function($query){ 
   $query->where('status', 'complete');
  }))->with(array('trades' => function($query){ 
   $query->where('status', 'success');
  }))->get()`

В итоге остался с ошибкой: http://prntscr.com/fogqs7

Comment: Обновил первый пост